# jQuery zoom function not working on hover image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using this library: https://www.jacklmoore.com/zoom/
It adds a zoom function when hovering over an image. I did add the library in my theme and added this jQuery code to my js file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.head-image img').zoom();
});
```

This is the HTML where the image is located:

```
<div class="head-image">
    <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('full'); ?>" class="img-fluid">
</div>
```

When I hover the image on the webpage nothing changes but if I look in the inspector I do see that the zoomImg class is added and the CSS is changing but I dont see the image zooming.

Here is the webpage URL: https://www.dev.ruitershopboxmeer.nl/paard/zadels-en-toebehoren/zadeldekjes/kingsland-zadeldekje-carin/

Does someone know why the image is not zooming?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: you have an error "jQuery is not defined".  include JQuery js file

Comment: @HithamS.AlQadheeb this is from another plugin. When I add console.log in the document ready function it is working so jQuery is included.

Comment: Another error in the console is `jQuery(...).elevateZoom is not a function`

Comment: jQuery might be included, but when it's called it's not defined. Without relevant code we can't really asses the issue.

Answer (score 0):

First fix the error in the beginning of the page (line 14 generated HTML)

```
<script>if(flycart_woo_discount_rules_strikeout_script_executed == undefined){jQuery( document ).ready( /* .... */
```

This needs to be moved at the end of the body to avoid issues

Next, make sure to include JQuery and Zoom correctly (from demo)

```
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='path/to/jquery.zoom.js'></script>
```

The imported JQuery is 3.4.1 and I am not sure Zoom is still compatible with it as demo was using 1.10.2.

Answer (score 0):

I have an alternate solution to your requirement here:

```
const img=document.querySelector('.image');
const pro=document.querySelector('.image img');

img.style.width=(pro.clientWidth)+'px';
var zoomSize = pro.clientHeight*6;
img.addEventListener('mousemove', printPosition);
img.addEventListener('mouseout', back);

function getPosition(e) {
  var rect = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
  var x = e.clientX - rect.left;
  var y = e.clientY - rect.top;
  return {
    x,
    y
  }
}

function printPosition(e) {
  var position = getPosition(e);
    xpos=position.x * (100/pro.clientWidth);
    ypos=position.y * (100/pro.clientHeight);
    pro.style.transition="0s";

    pro.style.transform='translate('+xpos*-5+'%, '+ypos*-5+'%)';
    pro.style.height=zoomSize+"px";

  console.log('X: ' + xpos + ' Y: ' + ypos);
}

function back(e) {
    pro.style.transform='translate(0px, 0px)';
    pro.style.height='100%';
    pro.style.transition="1s";
}
```

https://codepen.io/thevectorator/pen/NWGeBPm